# imageio: How to increase quality of output gifs?

Tags: python, image, animation, gif, freeimage

- I have a list of .png (PIL) images I want to string together into an animated gif
- To do this, I am currently using the `imageio` library
- However, I cannot find a way to do this to produce **good quality** gifs

As far as I know, there are two types of settings I can change. The `imageio.imread()` settings for reading .pngs, and the `imageio.mimwrite()` settings for writing gifs. According to `imageio.help()`,

1. `imageio.imread()` has *one* read paramter only for `PNG-PIL`, `ignoregamma` which takes a boolean. This does not change anything for my output gifs.
2. `imageio.mimwrite()` can refer to two formats. The first is `GIF-PIL`. The output from this format **only shows one frame**, and is thus undesirable. [Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md9vW.gif).
3. `imageio.mimwrite()` has the second format `GIF-FI`. This produces more promising outputs with the following options:

   - `'quantizer':'wu'` generates a full gif with specified frames and frame rates, but **produces a 'corrupted' kind-of quality**. [Output here](https://i.imgur.com/wMButp1.gif).
   - `'quantizer':'nq'` generates a full gif with better 'less corrupted' quality than 'wu', but **does not handle colour well**. Notice how the legend in the bottom right tends to change its colour. [Output here](https://i.imgur.com/kRln007.gif).

---

Here's the relevant code for the best quality I could get so far (`GIF-FI` with `nq`)

```
def gen_gif(self, datetime_list):
    kwargs_write = {'fps':5.0, 'quantizer':'nq'}
    frames = []
    for datetime in datetime_list:
        frames.append(imageio.imread(datetime+'.png'))
    exportname = '{} to {}.gif'.format(datetime_list[0], datetime_list[-1])
    imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, 'GIF-FI', **kwargs_write)
```

The function is called with one list parameter of strings containing the full path to the .png images to be compiled to the gif.

Answer (score 2):

The GIF format can only handle 256 colors per frame. The `quantizer` parameter determines the method that will be used to find these colors.

The best way to control which colors will be used is probably to reduce the number of colors (to 256) on your own.

Comment: Are there better tools than imageio to produce quality gif's?

Comment: Quality is directly liked to the way the images are downgraded to 256 colors, i.e. the quantization algorithm. In imageio, it seems that [GIF-PIL](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/pillowmulti.py#L363) uses the Neuquant algortihm, and [GIF-FI](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_gif-fi.html#gif-fi) proposes either Wu or Dekker.
Other algorithms -or even manual tweaking- may give better results depending on your images.